# Where is the most authoritative/complete source of documentation on rpm-python module?

Tags: python, rpm, rhel5

Trying to learn how to use the rpm-python module (i.e. "import rpm" on RHEL5). I can't find any tutorials that are complete or recent. Specifically regarding how to install and manage rpm's on a system. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some [documentation on Fedora](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch-rpm-programming-python.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on RHEL then you could seriously consider using the yum APIs instead of rpm-python directly ... the API is much easier to use.

Comment: One requirement I have is for offline installations. Yum requires a network connection to a repository, right?

Comment: No, you can use yum without any repos. (installing rpms from disk files). You can also call: yum.rpmsack.RPMDBPackageSack() directly for queries.

Answer (score 0):

Centos 5.6 uses rpm 4.4.2.3. I'd go with the [Developer Documentation](http://rpm.org/wiki/Docs#DeveloperDocumentation)